# Javascript Radio Validate using For Loop

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, radio-button

**Validate the radio button list by adding a for loop???**

I cannot figure out how to create a for loop to validate my subscriptions for the HTML radio buttons; Free, Basic, Premium.

- Line 39 for JS problem.
- Line 128 for HTML reference.

See snippet below:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>javascript form validation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     
     function checkme() {
      //alert("function fires");
    
      var error = "";
    
      if(document.getElementById('myname').value == "") {
       error = "Please enter your name.\n";
      }
    
      if(document.getElementById('state').selectedIndex==0) {
       error += "Please choose a state.\n";
      }
    
      if(document.getElementById('address').value== "") {
       error += "Please complete address.\n";
      }
      if(document.getElementById('city').value== "") {
       error += "Please complete city.\n";
      }
      if(document.getElementById('zip').value== "") {
       error += "Please complete address.\n";
      }
      if(document.getElementById('phone').value== "") {
       error += "Please enter phone number.\n";
      }
      if(document.getElementById('email').value== "") {
       error += "Please enter email.\n";
      }
      if(document.getElementById('comments').value== "") {
       error += "Please enter comments.\n";
      }
      if(!document.getElementById('radio')!=null){
       error += "Please select subscription.\n";
       // ????
    
      }
      if(!document.getElementById('terms')!=null){
       error += "Please accept terms.\n";
      }
    
      // Do not add logic below this comment
      if(error=="") {
       return true;
      }
      else {
       alert(error);
       return false;
      }
    
     }
    </script>
    <!-- styles for form -->
    <style type="text/css">
    fieldset {width: 400px;}
    
    /* zero ul and li */
    fieldset ul, fieldset li{
    border:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none;
    }
    
    /* li is a block level element. give margin bottom for spacing. */
    fieldset li
    {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    /* label is a inline element. convert to inline block to prevent wrapping to next line but still apply width. */
    fieldset label{
    width:140px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
    
    /* set radio button labels back to default */
    label.radios
    {
    width:100%;
    display: inline;
    }
    
    /* take lblnotes out of document flow, aligns to top */
    #lblnotes {float: left;}
    
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Sign-up Form</legend>
    <form id="the_form" name="the_form" action="FormProcessor.html" method="get" onsubmit="return checkme();">
    <ul>
    <li><label for="myname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" size="30" />
    </li>
    <li><label for="address">Street Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30" />
    </li>
    <li><label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30" />
    </li>
    <li><label for="state">State</label>
    <select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="none">choose a state</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    </select>
    </li>
    <li><label for="zip">Zip</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" size="30" />
    </li>
    <li><label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" />
    </li>
    <li><label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
    </li>
    
    <li><label for="comments" id="lblnotes">Commments</label>
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
    </li>
    
    <li><label>Subscription</label> <label for="free" class="radios">Free</label>
    <input type="radio" name="subscription" id="free"/>
    
    <label for="basic" class="radios">Basic</label>
    <input type="radio" name="subscription" id="basic"/>
    
    <label for="premium" class="radios">Premium</label>
    <input type="radio" name="subscription" id="premium"/>
    </li>
    
    <li>
    <label for="terms">Do you agree to terms?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms"/>
    </li>
    
    <li><label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button> </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the name of the radio button instead:

```
var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName(radioButtonName);

  for(var opt in radiobuttons ) {
    //validate...
  }
```

Comment: interesting work around. opt in is a command that we haven't touched on yet. thx

Comment: just to clarify, "opt in" isn't a command. opt is just a variable here, the loop i used is just a variation of for loop which is known as for/in loop in javascript. see this http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_for_in for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be to set `required` attribute at `input`, `textarea`, `select` elements

```js
var elems = document.forms["the_form"]
.querySelectorAll("input:not([type=submit]), select, textarea");

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].setAttribute("required", true)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>javascript form validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
<!-- styles for form -->
<style type="text/css">
fieldset {width: 400px;}

/* zero ul and li */
fieldset ul, fieldset li{
border:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none;
}

/* li is a block level element. give margin bottom for spacing. */
fieldset li
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* label is a inline element. convert to inline block to prevent wrapping to next line but still apply width. */
fieldset label{
width:140px;
display: inline-block;
}

/* set radio button labels back to default */
label.radios
{
width:100%;
display: inline;
}

/* take lblnotes out of document flow, aligns to top */
#lblnotes {float: left;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<fieldset>
<legend>Sign-up Form</legend>
<form id="the_form" name="the_form" action="FormProcessor.html" method="get" onsubmit="return checkme();">
<ul>
<li><label for="myname">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" size="30" />
</li>
<li><label for="address">Street Address</label>
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30" />
</li>
<li><label for="city">City</label>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30" />
</li>
<li><label for="state">State</label>
<select name="state" id="state">
<option value="none">choose a state</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
</select>
</li>
<li><label for="zip">Zip</label>
<input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" size="30" />
</li>
<li><label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" />
</li>
<li><label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
</li>

<li><label for="comments" id="lblnotes">Commments</label>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
</li>

<li><label>Subscription</label> <label for="free" class="radios">Free</label>
<input type="radio" name="subscription" id="free"/>

<label for="basic" class="radios">Basic</label>
<input type="radio" name="subscription" id="basic"/>

<label for="premium" class="radios">Premium</label>
<input type="radio" name="subscription" id="premium"/>
</li>

<li>
<label for="terms">Do you agree to terms?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms"/>
</li>

<li><label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button> </li>
</ul>
</form>
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Geez you guys got around to this super fast! I'll take a look at the solutions offered so far

Comment: @Blender and guest271314 this answer relies on the UI of the browser. I don't like reliance.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the radio buttons with the name subscriptions to find which if any is checked. Check the sample here (getRadioVal function): http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/get-selected.php

Comment: thanks this is prob what my instructor is looking for by the book